# How to get the exact used RAM percentage in Grafana?

Tags: linux, bash, grafana, influxdb, collectd

AM using **collectd** to collect the metrics from the system, am using **Influxdb** as a database to collectd the metrics and **Grafana** for visualization.
I need only the **used RAM memory in percentage** to display in grafana....

As of now i query grafana like

```
SELECT mean("value") *-1+100 FROM "memory_value" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/ AND "type" = 'percent' AND "type_instance" = 'free') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval),"host"
```

Which gives the wrong value..
Can anyone pls help me how to display the used RAM percentage

Comment: you need to check which all fields you are collecting as part of RAM metric name `memory_value`, different types of fields can be `free` or `available_percentage` etc, note: this fields can be different based on which metric plugin you are using to collect it.

Comment: @dkb when i run free -m some values are showing up like free available etc...In that i need the total value of buffer+cache(used)/total ..HOw can i query this value in grafana...

Comment: @dkb <Plugin memory>
    ValuesAbsolute true
    ValuesPercentage true
</Plugin> this is what i gave in collectd.conf